# Django Caching with Users

Tags: django, memcached, django-cache, django-caching

I was wondering if there is a way to cache querysets to memcache on a site that has authenticated users and users that are not authenticated.

Basically I just need to cache queries from one table.

Any ideas would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check out [johnny-cache](https://pythonhosted.org/johnny-cache/). This worked great for us until we did so much writing (updating records) that we were invalidating cache constantly. At that point we just started using memcache directly, like this.

```
cache.set("some_unique_key", my_queryset, 3600)
cache_object = cache.get(cache_key)
```

If you're dealing with large querysets or objects, you might want to pickle them first.

```
cache.set("some_unique_key", zlib.compress(cPickle.dumps(cache_object), 1), 3600)
zipped_cache_object = cache.get(cache_key)
if zipped_cache_object:
    cache_object = cPickle.loads(zlib.decompress(zipped_cache_object))
```

[Django's Caching Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/)

Comment: Looks like what I need (johnny-cache) however it is not working in 1.6 and I see its an open issue on github

Comment: If you're just looking to cache a single table, use memcache directly. Are you trying to cache calls to a django built-in like auth_user or are you looking to cache something you've built yourself?